# specific solution of Prove that $N_p(H) \ne H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, p-groups

this is not a duplicate .. I'm trying to understand a specific answer of this question. the parts that I don't understand are marked in (1) , (2), (3) and explanations for what i don't understand are in the bottom. thanks

P is a p group and H is a proper subgroup of P . Prove that $N_p(H) \ne H$

I saw many answers but I'm trying to understand a specific one and having difficulties:

my answer is as follows -

Im trying to find a specific $p \in N_p(H)$ such that $p \notin H$

I look at the group $X = \{pH |p \in P \}$

and the operation of ?(1)? on X

$ h \in H$

$ \pi (pH) = hpH$

from the orbit stabiliser i get

$|X| = \sum_I [P:P_{x_i}] + |x_0|$  ?(2)?

for each i,

$p|[P:P_{x_i}]$ because it is an index of a p group ?(3)?

from here i assume p divides $x_0$ and i show an element in $x_0$ which

is in $N_p(H)$ and not not in H.

What I don't understand in this solution is -

(1) who operates on X? is it P or H?

(2) I assumed in (1) that it is H operating on X because they mention $h \in H$, than how come

they use P in the orbit stabiliser theorem?

(3) please help me understand why  $p | [P:P_{x_i}]$

any help will be very appreciated ,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this theorem holds (and the proof is identical) with the more general hypothesis:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a $p$-subgroup such that $p | [G : H]$.

[Clearly if $G$ is a $p$-group then any subgroup is a $p$-subgroup and the fact that $H$ is proper implies that $p | [G : H]$.]

Let $X = \{gH\, .\, g \in G\}$ be the set of left cosets of $H$, then we consider the action

$$
\begin{align*}
H \times X &\to X\\
(h, gH) &\mapsto (hg)H
\end{align*}
$$

[The answers to (1) is therefore that it is $H$ acting on the set of left cosets by left multiplication.]

Now, by orbit-stabilizer theorem the order of any orbit is a divisor of $H$, but since $H$ is a $p$-subgroup it must be power of $p$. Also, it is known that $X$ is the disjoint union of its orbits, so

$$p | [G : H] = |X| = \sum_{\substack{O_x \in X_G \\ p | |O_x|}} |O_x| + \sum_{\substack{O_x \in X_G \\ |O_x| = 1}} 1$$

What I'm doing is to separate the sum between the orbits whose order is divisible by $p$ and these of order $p^0 = 1$.

Since all the terms of the first summatory are divisible by $p$ it follows that the second summatory, which is essentialy the number of trivial orbits, is divisible by $p$. Since $H$ has a trivial orbit it follows that there are at least other $p-1$ trivial orbits. Let $\{gH\}$ be one of these, being the only element in the orbit means $H g H = g H$, then

$$g^{-1} H g \subseteq g^{-1} H g H = g^{-1} g H = H$$

this proves that $g \in N_G(H)$, where $g \notin H$.

You can also infer that $gH$ is in $N_G(H)$ by remembering that $N_G(H)$ is a group and therefore closed under product.

To conclude, I don't really understand after $\pi (p H) = \ldots$ but here are my guess-answer to (2) and (3):

$P$ (or $G$ in my setting) arises from the orbit stabilizer theorem: $O_x \cong G / G_x$, so $|O_x| = [G : G_x]$, I avoided this passage though.

$p | [G:G_x]$ because $G_x$ is a subgroup of $H$, therefore $[G:G_x] = [G:H]\, [H:G_x]$ and we know that $[G:H]$ is divisible by $p$.

As a bonus, if you continue this proof just a bit you get the first Sylow theorem, as it has been suggested [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.07235v1.pdf), upper part of page 3.

P.S. with $X_G$ I mean the orbit space, the quotient by the usual equivalence relation given by the action, the place where the orbits live.

Comment: thanks a lot ! i understand much better now